# como insertar varios registros a la vez en una base de datos SQL?

Tags: sql, matlab

**¿Hay una forma de insertar todos los datos de los vectores X? Rango y Valido son variables de un solo dato**

Las x son vectores de 24 datos por vector y los numeros columnas, los demas son variables de un solo dato

```
query = sprintf("INSERT INTO dbo.Datos ([FechaHora],[Presion],[Volumen],[Energia],[id_Distribucion],[RangoOperacional],[Valido]) VALUES (%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d)",x1,x2,x3,x4,id3,RangoOp,Valido);
```

Comment: Un metodo forEach te podria funcionar

Comment: Las funciones [insert](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.odbc.connection.insert.html) o [sqlwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.odbc.connection.sqlwrite.html) (esta última disponible en MATLAB 2020) ¿no te sirven?.